# SteamPlay Elite Dangerous - Recognizing Logitech Extreme 3D Pro Joystick as 'Generic Gamepad'

Tags: games, steam, logitech, joystick

I switched from W10 to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS some days ago, and up until now, I have found solutions for all my noob questions about stuff.

But recently, I installed Steam and tried to install *Elite Dangerous: Horizons*. I got it up and working on Proton 4.11-7 with the mouse, but I had always been using my trusty Logitech Extreme 3D Pro Joystick on Windows 10 when playing the game, but when trying to set up the joystick on Ubuntu, I immediately ran into a lot of problems.
When I look at 'General Controller Settings' I can see that Steam for some reason thinks that my joystick is a *Generic Gamepad* ??

[image: Picture of General Controller Settings]

I thought that that was pretty weird, and Elite Dangerous thinks the same too when I fire up the game. Steam thinks that my joystick is a Generic Gamepad and I don't know why?

**What I've tried:**

1. I've tried re-installing Elite Dangerous. No effect.
2. I've tried setting the 'Steam Input Per-Game Setting' to 'Forced Off'. No effect.
3. Tested the joystick with `jstest-gtk`. *It* is recognizing it correctly as a joystick!
4. I also tried launching ED in Big Picture Mode and tried Steam Beta Release... No effect at all.

Please help. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know people have had success with the following:
https://github.com/redmcg/wine/wiki/Peripherals#logitech-extreme-3d-pro

1. Disable SDL by setting 'Enable SDL' off (with: wine64 reg add 'HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WineBus' /v 'Enable SDL' /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f); and
2. Delete all registry entries with your PID and VID (for example: look in system.reg and remove any line with VID_046D&PID_C215)

---

Edit:

Apologies - I just copy and pasted the above when I had a brief moment this morning. But you might find the below to be a bit more helpful:

If you're using protontricks, step one can be done by running:
`protontricks 359320 regedit` and then navigating to:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WineBus`

And creating a new DWORD value called `Enable SDL` with a value of `0`. This disables SDL.

You can then click on `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System` and do a `Find` (Ctrl+F) for the string `VID_046D&PID_C215` and delete every entry you find.

VID = Vendor ID  (0x046D = Logitech)

PID = Product ID (0xC215 = Extreme 3D Pro Joystick)

The reason you need to do the above is because SDL incorrectly thinks this device is a controller. It then creates those incorrect registry entries that tell ED that it's a controller.

By disabling SDL - Wine falls back to using the kernel driver (evdev, which does not think it's a controller) and Wine will then rewrite those registry entries telling ED that it's a joystick.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I have now been confirmed by others that this fixed the issue. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you are using protontricks from flathub, use the following command `flatpak run --command=protontricks com.valvesoftware.Steam`. You will then be able to search around for your game's ID and run the `regedit`command. For Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020, this looks something like: `flatpak run --command=protontricks com.valvesoftware.Steam 1250410 regedit`. You can then follow the rest of this answer.